# how do i translate from s[-4:] to s[slice(???)] in python? not" s[slice(s, len(s))]"

Tags: python, string, slice

I know `s[slice(s, len(s))]` would work,
but it is possible to not getting the length of the string,
and still using builtin method `slice` in python,
it seems there is no way to work it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "null" value for all slice parts is `None`.

```
slice(-4, None)
```